# Javascript focus on input box on load

Tags: javascript, html, input, dom-events

No matter what I do, this page doesn't work at all. I want it to focus on the input box on load.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Screen</title>
<style type="text/css">
input {border:0px;}
input:focus {outline:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById("search").focus()">
<input id="search" />
</body>
</html>
```

I know I'm breaking a bunch of rules with this code, so you don't need to say anything about that.

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Screen</title>
<style type="text/css">
input {border:0px;}
input:focus {outline:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('search').focus()">
<input id="search" onblur="setTimeout(document.getElementById('search').focus(),10)" />
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refocus()
{
setTimeout(document.getElementById("search").focus(),10);
}
</script>

<input id="search" onblur="refocus()" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quotes cannot include double quotes,not only in javascript,any other language is the same.

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('search').focus()">
```

Comment: OK, I updated the page, and this other focus isn't working. (Edit)

Comment: For the onblur method,you may need to declare a function，because inline coding cannot be surrounded by quotes nested more than 2 times。setTimeout's first argument should be surrounded by quotes...

Comment: try:setTimeout("document.getElementById('search').focus()",10);

Comment: I had this same issue, would love to know why you have to use the setTimeout method and can't call the function/event directly?

Comment: @LeeTickett did you find out?

Answer (score 2):

I'f you're using jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#search").focus();
});
```

or prototype:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  $("search").focus();
});
```

or plain javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("search").focus();
};
```

It's "Better" for readability than an inline event...

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `search` into single quotes:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('search').focus()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put search in single quotes, since you have double quotes around the document.getelementbyid

```
 <body onload="document.getElementById('search').focus()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your experiencing this issue because you're using the same quotes inside the onfocus event, you can change `"search"` to `'search'` to fix the issue.

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('search').focus()">
```

Ideally though, you should attach your events in JavaScript so your markup stays clear and all functional aspects of the page are located in one place.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dp2Cj/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("search").focus();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set some delay in your code by using setTimeout function to resolve this problem.

```
function fireOnClick() {
    // Set text filed focus after some delay
    setTimeout(function() { jQuery('#globalText').focus() }, 20);
    // Do your work.....
}
```